# Order of save() and find() in NodeJS with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a new record in my MongoDB ("thisPlayer") and save it to my database, then find all records in my database (including the new one) and render them.

I am having trouble understanding why my save() function actually occurs after my find() function. When this code executes, the find() function does not include my new thisPlayer record. However, after the find() runs, the save occurs -- the record is saved to the database AFTER the find() ran.

Thanks in advance!

```
    const playerNumber = async function countPlayers() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          Player.count(function(err, numOfDocs) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(numOfDocs);
            console.log('I have '+numOfDocs+' documents in my collection');
          });
        });  
    }
      
    async function playerProfile() {
        var count = await playerNumber();
        console.log("count already in db: "+ count);
        
        if (count===0) {
            teamCaptain=1;
        } else {teamCaptain=0};
        
        count++;


        const thisPlayer = new Player({
                playerNum: count,
                playerName: Name,
            });
              
            thisPlayer.save();
    
            Player.find({}, function(err, playaz){

                var playerOne;
    
                if (playaz.length > 0) {
                    playerOne = playaz[0].playerName;
                } else {
                    playerOne = "";
                }
            
                res.renderPjax("leavetakings",
                    {player1: "1: " + playerOne}
                );
            });
    
        }
        
        playerProfile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use await
for example.

```
 await Player.find({})
```

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't appear to change what's happening. When I change it to const playaz = await Player.find() it continues to first read the thisPlayer.save() line but not execute it (I can see this when I log thisPlayer on the line right after the save() line). Then it runs the find() and renders the data that does not include the record that should have been saved. It then saves the record after the render has happened, when I look at the database after the code has fully executed.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to add the await to the save() function as well!